# firefox: sourcemaps load does not work

Tags: firefox

I am developing with firefox. I have an uglified javascript with accompanying source map. With chrome everything works ok , but on firefox (even developer version) I get

Error loading source: loadSourceError

How can i get more information why the map cannot be loaded? 
What could be the reason?